# issue in indexing solr data

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, solrj

Issue is how to index this data properly so that querying can be possible as well.

I need to get the data of events on the basis of date, day of week and time slot. My primary id is event id.

- Table1-

  ```
  select event_id, from_date, to_date from event_listing. event_id is primary key.
  ```
- Table2

  ```
  select dayOfWeek, slot_start_time, slot_end_time from slot_data where event_id = $eventId
  ```

I need to index these data in solr, like - I'll get only one record for one particular event.

Once data is indexed, I need  to query this data on the basis of- time slots and `dayOfweek`.

Let me know the suitable way to get this.

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to index each event/date/start_time/end_time as as individual Solr documents. You can then query by either event_id, by date/time range as you please. The data will not come grouped as a single document, but you can then use facets or other Solr filtering options to group the data (or group it in your app.) Keep in mind that Solr is not a relational database and you might be better off not trying to mimic your relational database in Solr and use a different data model.

Comment: A date range field should be able to let you query events by timeslot; i.e. you index a multivalued field with a daterange that notes every interval that the event is active in. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @HectorCorrea got it, can you answer my query regarding to solr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073742/solr-date-range-issue