# solr date range issue

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

I have solr query

I have list of dateTimeStamp i.e user_input_datetimeList which I want to check lying in indexed data i.e indexed_datetime_range_List  eg

indexed_datetime_range_List:["2021-08-27T00:00:00Z TO 2021-08-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-08-2T00:00:00Z TO 2021-08-12T00:00:00Z", "2021-08-25T02:21:00Z TO 2021-09-25T02:21:00Z"]

indexed_datetime_range_List2:["2021-05-27T00:00:00Z-2021 TO 05-31T00:00:00Z", "2021-01-2T00:00:00Z TO 2021-01-12T00:00:00Z", "2021-02-25T02:21:00Z TO 2021-04-25T02:21:00Z"]

user_input_datetimeList:[2021-08-28T00:00:00Z,2021-08-24T00:00:00Z,2021-010-27T00:00:00Z]

I want to checked, is any datetime of user_input_datetimeList is lying in indexed_datetime_range_List. Even if its true for one date then I want to return true and if none found return false.

here indexed_datetime_range_List retun true and indexed_datetime_range_List2 return false